# Explain the output (2-D arrays in C)

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I wrote the code as follows :

```
#include<stdio.h>
    int main() {
        int arr[3][2]={{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}};
        printf("%d %d %d",arr[0][3],arr[1][2],arr[2][0]);
        return 0;
    }
```

And the (GCC) output is :

```
4 5 5
```

Please explain this output. According to my approach the code should throw an error because there is no column indexed as 3 or 2.

Comment: It is undefined behavior.

Comment: You can expect __any__ output as a result.

Comment: It would be helpful if anybody explains why i got -3 on my question :/ . I don't think i did  violate any rules here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is flawed code. your array bounds are out of range.  However, they obviously still reference real data.  If you have a multidimensional array `arr[NUMROWS][NUMCOLS]`, the array is still stored in memory contiguously.  To access element `arr[x][y]`, then you are looking for the element in position `x*NUMCOLS+y`.  For your problem, arr exists in memory as 1 2 3 4 5 6.  `arr[0][3]` refers to **element at index 0*2+3, which is 4** (remember arrays are 0 indexed).  Similarly, `arr[1][2]` corresponds to **1*2+2 = 4, which is 5**.  Lastly `arr[2][0] = 2*2 + 0=4`, so you **again get 5**.

Answer (score 0):

In C it is not guaranteed to throw an error if you access out of an array's bounds. In fact, the C standard places no requirements on what the compiler must do in this situation. The reason for this is so that the compiler can produce the most optimal output for legal programs without having to worry about stopping you from shooting yourself in the foot.